# Locate Blazor Webassembly downloaded .dll files on disk?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I want to locate the **.dll** files that has been shipped by **Blazor** (Web Assembly) to browsers like Chrome to see if the **.dll** files can be read by disassemblers(like Reflector) or not. I found the files in Chrome's

> Developers tool(F12) > Application tab > Cache Storage

but can not find them on the disk.

**Update :** Suppose that I want the get access to some else's Blazor website's **.dll** files.
Where are the following files on website visitor's computer?

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Current answer is basically correct. You see yourself on screenshot above (with cache) that those files were fetched via url, from your server (http://localhost:58996/_framework/ClassLibrary2.dll). So anyone who wants to get them don't need to find where and how chrome stores its cache - he can just request this url

Comment: @Evk  but when I do this I get 404.11 Not Found status with following error message :
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.

Comment: Try with url from my comment (so remove all that sha256 etc, leave only path to dll)

Comment: Here is a good article describing some details: https://blog.ndepend.com/blazor-internals-you-need-to-know/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this utility - https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html

On windows Chrome cache location is - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

This utility work with latest Microsoft Edge for Chrome also. It's cache location on windows is - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Cache

Answer (score 3):

As @Gursharan points out they are saved inside of a binary database stored in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache`.

If you want to read them from your local disk you need use a utility to read Chrome's binary cache.

Alternately you can download them using the `Request URL` shown in Chrome's Cache Storage.

For example:

1. Visit following [sample blazor app](https://jsakamoto.github.io/awesome-blazor-browser,%20the%20https://jsakamoto.github.io/awesome-blazor-browser/)
2. Open `Application > Cache Storage > blazor-resources/awesome-blazor-browser` in Chrome developer tools.
3. Select a .dll resource.
4. In the headers tab and highlight the `Request URL` up until the .dll extension (highlighted in yellow below)
5. Right click and choose  `Go To` (shown in the bottom screen shot)
6. If the assembly is signed and trusted it will download automatically. For example, netstandard.dll. Otherwise you need to click keep in the permissions prompt.

[image: Go To]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The .dll files will be at the project folder, IIS Express runs the project directly from there, e.g. if on the `Developers tool(F12) > Application tab > Cache Storage` you see something like `/_framework/_bin/Blazor%20WebAssembly.dll.sha256-dTdRmYzYOZYhTcSkqvmzcmpD/Pi03agjQ4oZTOgt8o8=` in the name, then it'll be found here when debugging:

`<project root>\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\wwwroot\_framework\_bin`

Comment: I want to get them from Chrome .

Comment: @nAviD what does it mean "_get them from Chrome_" ? Chrome only makes a request to IIS Express, the app is hosted by IIS Express and served from the folder in the answer, including the **.dll** files you asked from disk

Comment: The dll files will be downloaded and run by Chrome. I want get those dll files. Suppose I don't have access to IIS Server or the project I just want to visit the website and find the downloaded dll files

Comment: What does it mean "_dll files will be downloaded and run by chrome_" ? Chrome runs the compiled binary WASM Mono.NET, the runtime is bootstrapped and it loads and executes those .dll files from disk.
 Maybe read this https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/26/whats-behind-the-hype-about-blazor/#:~:text=Currently%2C%20Blazor%20WebAssembly%20uses%20interpreted,WebAssembly%20is%20the%20Mono%20runtime
In a nutshell **The only part of the process that is compiled to WebAssembly is the Mono runtime**

Comment: So you confirm that my app's dll files will be downloaded ? other than cache files, the blazor also notify in console which files ( and sized) have been dowloaded by the browser . Am I right?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking in the comment, the question was getting the `.dll` files from disk that Blazor runs, which is what the answer provides.